# A non-separable strictly convex space with a separable pre-dual

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am asked to find an example of a non-separable strictly convex space with a separable pre-dual.
So please give me some hints or some references about such problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clarkson (1936) was the first to prove that if a normed space $X$ is separable, then $X$ is isomorphic to a strictly convex space. We will use the following, which can be found in the paper of Day mentioned below and which follows immediately from Clarkson's work.

> **Fact:** if $X$ is separable, then $X^*$ is isomorphic to a strictly convex space.

**Sketch:** the unit sphere of $X$ is separable. So take a countable dense set $\{x_n\,;\,n\geq 1\}$ in the latter. Now consider for every $x^*\in X^*$ the sequence $Tx^*:=\left(\frac{x^*(x_n)}{2^n} \right)_{n\geq 1}$. This yields a linear injection into the strictly convex space $\ell^2$. The new norm
$$
\|x^*\|_{sc}:=\|x^*\|+\|Tx^*\|_2
$$
is equivalent to the dual norm $\|x^*\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|x^*(x)|$ and it is strictly convex. $\Box$

**Remark:** then it suffices to renorm $X$ by $\|x\|:=\sup_{\|x^*\|_{sc}\leq 1}|x^*(x)|$ to get an equivalent norm on $X$ for which the dual is $X^*$ with this strictly convex norm. As pointed out by Martin, Klee expanded on Clarkson's idea to show that all this could be done in such a way that $X$ be smooth.

> **Application:** $\ell^\infty$ is neither separable nor strictly convex. But it is the dual of the separable space $\ell^1$. So by the fact above, $\ell^\infty$ can be renormed into a strictly convex space. If you want a noncommutative example, take $B(H)$ and renorm it as the dual of $S_1(H)$ the separable space of trace-class operators.

**References:** see the [free access](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-078-02/S0002-9947-1955-0067351-1/home.html) article by Day for details and more on strict convexity and smoothness in normed spaces. See the appendix of this  [other free access](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1953-074-01/S0002-9947-1953-0054850-X/home.html) paper of Klee (thanks Martin again) for more details.

Comment: I have the same idea but thought this is a mosquito nuking, anyway +1

Comment: @Norbert Do you know an easier example? That would be nice...

Comment: No, I don't....

Comment: It's worth adding that Klee showed that $\lVert x^\ast \rVert_{\rm sc}$ obtained by this construction actually is the dual norm of a smooth norm equivalent to the original norm on $X$. @Norbert: It is the standard example and it seems easy enough...

Comment: @Martin I always thought that fact is something advanced, and did not know the proof. That's why I though that way.

Comment: @Norbert: You do need a lot of concepts. However, deciphering Day's paper might be the hardest thing about this result :-)

Comment: @Martin Thank you. By the way, doesn't it suffice to set $\|x\|_{sm}:=\sup_{\|x^*\|_{sc}\leq 1}\|x^*(x)\|$ to get the smooth renorming of $X$?

Comment: @Hamid: You should thank julien, not me :-)

Comment: @Hamid No problem. We should always thank Martin anyway!

Comment: Yes, of course $\lVert x \rVert_{\rm sm}$ is necessarily given by this expression. The details are given in A1.1 and A1.2 on page 37 of Klee, [Convex bodies and periodic homeomorphisms in Hilbert space](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1953-0054850-X), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 74 (1953), 10-43.

Comment: @Martin Thanks a lot for the reference.